# Content does not jump into next page

Tags: table-of-contents, margins, two-column, ieeetran, cuted

I am writing a two-page document. However, I found that using `@twocolumnfalse` or `strip` environment my content does not follow on a new page.

The snippet of the code is:

```
\documentclass[journal, a4paper, 10pt]{IEEEtran}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[acronym, toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,citestyle=numeric,sorting=none,hyperref,backend=biber,backref,backrefstyle=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
      \printfield{labelprefix}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{3pt}
\urlstyle{tt}
\usepackage{url}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a markup language specially suited for 
scientific documents}
}


\newglossaryentry{formula}
{
    name=formula,
    description={A mathematical expression}
}

\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}
\newacronym{lcm}{LCM}{Least Common Multiple}



\input{title_page}

\begin{document}


\twocolumn[{%
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
        % \noindent 
        \lipsum
    \end{abstract}
    \vspace{3mm}
    \hspace{5mm} \small{\textbf{Keywords}: this, that}
    \vspace{5mm}
    \printglossary
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables

  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
}]



\section{\textbf{INTRODUCTION}}


Given a set of numbers, there are elementary methods to compute 
its \acrlong{gcd}, which is abbreviated \acrshort{gcd}. This process 
is similar to that used for the \acrfull{lcm}.

The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. \Glspl{formula} are rendered 
properly an easily once one gets used to the commands.


\section{\textbf{METHODOLOGY}}

\subsection{\textbf{Overview}}

\subsection{\textbf{Algorithm}}

\section{\textbf{RESULTS}}

\section{\textbf{CONCLUSIONS}}


\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\printbibliography




\end{document}
```

How it is rendered now:
[image]

How it should look like:
[image]

Comment: the optional argument to `\twocolum` is a box that spans over two columns it can never be more than a page long. move all that frontmatter _before_ `\twocolumn` and use `\onecolumn` at the start

Comment: Oh, then I'll just use ```\onecolumn``` instead! Thanks for it!